# what is the equivalent test attribute for TestFixtureSetUp of Nunit in MSTest

Tags: mstest

In NUnit we use `TestFixtureSetUp` what is the equivalent test in MSTest?

Thanks

Answer (score 33):

here you can find good table which shows NUnit and MSTest attributes side by side:

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/nunit-vs-xunit-vs-mstest/

for your answer it's `ClassInitialize` attribute

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 21):

You're looking for the [`[ClassInitialize]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext) { ... }
```

Comment: hmm... but this method has to be static... which means it can't be used to initialize class instance variables... or am I missing something.

Comment: @EoinCampbell: You could use the constructor.